# Separating different messages of an email message

Tags: c#, .net, email, pop3

Is it possible to divide a "multi time replied" message to it's containing messages?

For Example: I send and email to my friend and he/she replies me. When I receive it, I need to display only the the new part in my program.

I currently use C#Mail in my program. Is there any other library out there that has this functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do what Gmail does and just find the diff between the body of a message and the body of the previous message. This is probably your most reliable option.

http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With difficulty. Different email clients have different ways of pointing out the reply.
If you're dealing with text-only emails, the reply is usually indented with > and preceded by something along the lines of "Original Message".
The ticket system I have uses something like this, and what it does is put a token at the start of its messages. This is then used to cut off where the original message starts, but the heading that says "Original Message" stays there...

Answer (score 0):

If the original is attached as a message, then all you need to do, is simply traverse the parts for the part that has a content type of rfc822/Message.

Once you have that part, decode it, and you should have the contents of the original message.

The problem is (like Kolink alludes to), some messages are sent as part of the body, so you need to sometimes extract the original message from the body.